# WebApi: How to call Facebook Graph API by using an access token originated from the OAuth dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have an ASP.NET WebApi 2.1 application with OAuth2 configured. I have and Android client where I can do authentication by using the following methods:

WebView approach (Web Api External Providers): redirect to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth..., user do login there, FB asks for permissions, redirects to my url, catch it, access token got, done.

Facebook SDK approach: under the hood it does: redirect to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth..., user do login there, FB asks for permissions, redirects to my url, catch it, access token got, done.

The problem is, if I go with the WebView version, the token is good for authorizing user in my Web Api application, but I cannot call Graph API by using it, I receive OAuthException 190 (no subcode).

But if I do the SDK authorization, Graph API is accessible (through the Android Facebook SDK), but using the token I've got from it, Web Api authorization is not working, I get 401 by calling Authorization/UserInfo.

So my question are the above token types interchangeable somehow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not know what you mean exactly by OAuth2 Web API configured are you using the Web API individual accounts template? 
I've posted earlier how we can obtain FB token (External Access Token) and then replace it with local access token (generated from local authority). So you will have 2 tokens now, the local one is good for Web API and the external one is good for calling FB graph API. 
Check it here http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

Comment: Thanks, you comment helped me to find a solution that fits into the project template that I'm using. I've explained my solution below.

Comment: You are welcome, if it was useful please vote up my comment.

Comment: I ain't got enough reputation to upvote comments yet, sorry! I'm back when I get, I promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if that was not clear, I'm using Web Api w/ ASP.NET Identity 2.0 template, so OAuth plumbing code is already present there.

I was able to find an answer to my own question, let me share it with you.

So the problem is that the token I've got from the Facebook's OAuth dialog after the redirect is not the same token that my application can use to call Facebook Graph APIs in the name of the actual user. That Graph API token is reachable at the following point:

Assume you are using the mentioned template above, you can find App_Data/Startup.Auth.cs class with definition of a FacebookAuthenticationOptions instance. There you can catch the API token and can persist that into the database. For example:

```
var fbopts = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = Global.Config.ExternalServices.FacebookAppID,
    AppSecret = Global.Config.ExternalServices.FacebookAppSecret,
    Scope = { "email", "user_friends", "publish_actions" },
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async context =>
        {
            // This token will be OK for calling Graph API
            string accessToken = context.AccessToken; 

            using (var tracer = Global.Tracer.CreateBuilder())
            {
                try
                {
                    tracer.InformationLine("Storing Facebook OAuth token: " + accessToken);
                    string fbUserID = context.Identity.GetUserId();
                    string fbUserName = context.Identity.Name;
                    tracer.InformationLine("Facebook User ID: " + fbUserID);
                    tracer.InformationLine("Facebook User Name: " + fbUserName);

                    // Store it into the db
                    // assume Task StoreOAuthToken(string providerName, string providerKey, string accessToken) is defined
                    await StoreOAuthToken("Facebook", fbUserID, accessToken);                       
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracer.ErrorLine("Failed.", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fbopts);
```

At this point you're gonna have a row in a table that consists of the following columns:

```
OAuthAccessToken.ProviderName
OAuthAccessToken.ProviderKey
OAuthAccessToken.AccessToken
```

Now you can provide an API to your consumers to have that API token for calling Graph API, like:

```
[Route("AccessTokens")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<List<OAuthAccessToken>> GetAccessTokens(string providerName = null)
{
    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var q = from l in this.Context.AspNetUserLogins // Managed by ASP.NET Identity 2.0
            from t in this.Context.OAuthAccessTokens // Stored by you with above code
            where l.UserId == userID && t.ProviderName == l.LoginProvider && t.ProviderKey == l.ProviderKey
            select t;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(providerName)) q = q.Where(t => t.ProviderName == providerName);

    return await q.ToListAsync();
}
```

So on Android after doing a Facebook login I have the Bearer token for my application's Web Api calls, and I can get my token for accessing Graph API by calling the action above.

Maybe there are easier methods for achieving the above. Please let me know if you find any.